# Matching a Slater-type wavefunction with a minimal (STO-nG) Gaussian basis set

Tags: computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, basis-set, quantum-chemistry

I have on hand a high-precision wavefunction expressed in Slater orbitals.  I need to express it as accurately as possible in a minimal Gaussian basis set.

For background: I am currently working with `STO-6G`, but it is not good enough to describe the cusp condition with the accuracy I need. How can I get to a basis like `STO-7G`, or even beyond to something like `STO-10G`, preferably in a form that is compatible with QChem?

Answer (score 12):

### TL;DR

The procedure to represent a Slater-type orbital (STO) as a linear combination of Gaussian-type orbitals (GTO) is outlined in [W. J. Hehre, R. F. Stewart and J. A. Pople, *J. Chem. Phys.* **1969,** *51*, 2657](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1672392) and is a quite straight forward least square fitting.

### Derivation

I'll be quoting/ rephrasing quite liberally and take the 1s orbital as an example. The STO is defined as
\begin{align}
\phi_\mathrm{1s}(\zeta_1, \mathbf{r}) &= 
  (\zeta_1^3/\pi)^{1/2}\exp(-\zeta_1 \mathbf{r}).
  \tag1\label{STO-1s}
\end{align}

The general form of a Gaussian-type 1s orbital is defined as
\begin{align}
g_\mathrm{1s}(\alpha, \mathbf{r}) &= 
  (2\alpha/\pi)^{3/4}\exp(-\alpha \mathbf{r}^2).
  \tag2\label{GTO-1s-general}
\end{align}

The STO is expressed as a sum of $K$ GTOs; the coefficients and exponents are obtained for a STO with $\zeta=1.0$ and the scaled uniformly. Hence we can write
\begin{align}
\phi_\mathrm{1s}'(\zeta, \mathbf{r}) &= 
  \zeta^{3/2}\phi_\mathrm{1s}'(1.0,\zeta\mathbf{r}),
  \tag3\label{GTO-1s-zeta1}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\phi_\mathrm{1s}'(1.0, \mathbf{r}) &= 
  \sum_k^K d_{\mathrm{1s},k}\,g_\mathrm{1s}(\alpha_k,\mathbf{r}).
  \tag4\label{GTO-1s-lc}
\end{align}

In order to obtain the coefficients $d$ and exponents $\alpha$ the contracted GTO is fitted to the form of the STO via a least square method. Note that this is a quite unique approach, since most other basis sets are optimised to produce the minimal energy. It all comes down to minimising the integral
\begin{align}
I &=
  \int \left(
         \phi_\mathrm{1s}(1.0,\mathbf{r})-\phi_\mathrm{1s}'(1.0,\mathbf{r})
       \right)^2 \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}.
  \tag5\label{min-int}
\end{align}

For $K=3$, i.e. STO-3G, the following values are obtained:
\begin{array}{llll}\hline
k & \alpha_{\mathrm{1s},k} & d_{\mathrm{1s},k}      & I\\\hline
  &                        &                        & 3.31\times10^{-4}\\
1 & 1.09818 \times10^{-1}  & 4.44635 \times10^{-1}  &\\
2 & 4.05771 \times10^{-1}  & 5.35328 \times10^{-1}  &\\
3 & 2.22766                & 1.54329 \times10^{-1}  &\\\hline
\end{array}

### Implementation

Finally you need to scale the exponents to use the right exponent. From $\eqref{GTO-1s-zeta1}$ we see 
$$\mathbf{r}\mapsto\zeta\mathbf{r}_{\zeta=1.0}$$
and from $\eqref{GTO-1s-general}$ we know $\mathbf{r}\mapsto\mathbf{r}^2$ and therefore the exponent
$$\alpha_\zeta\mapsto\alpha_{\zeta=1.0}\zeta^2.$$

Hydrogen for example has $\zeta=1.24$ (Tab. IX) and therefore the exponents that need to be implemented are:
\begin{array}{lll}\hline
k & \alpha_{\mathrm{1s},k} & d_{\mathrm{1s},k}      \\\hline
1 &       0.16885540       &      0.44463454        \\
2 &       0.62391373       &      0.53532814        \\
3 &       3.42525091       &      0.15432897        \\\hline
\end{array}

For Q-Chem this is explained in the [manual under 7.4.3](http://www.q-chem.com/qchem-website/manual_4-1.html#tth_sEc7.4.3) and needs to have the form
\begin{array}{llll}
\text{\$basis}\\
\ce{X} & 0\\   
L & K & \text{scale}\\
α_1  & C_1^{L_\mathrm{min}} & C_1^{L_\mathrm{min}+1} &\dots& C_1^{L_\mathrm{max}}&\\
α_2  & C_2^{L_\mathrm{min}} & C_2^{L_\mathrm{min}+1} &\dots& C_2^{L_\mathrm{max}}&\\
\vdots    & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
α_K  & C_K^{L_\mathrm{min}} & C_K^{L_\mathrm{min}+1} &\dots& C_K^{L_\mathrm{max}}&\\
\text{****}\\
\text{\$end}\\
\end{array}
where $\ce{X}$ is the atomic symbol, $L$ is the angular momentum, $K$ is the degree of contraction, $\text{scale}$ is the scaling applied to all exponents, $\alpha_i$ are the exponents, and $C_i^L$ are the contraction coefficients.

As a practical example, the STO-3G basis set shall look like this:

```
$basis
   H   0
   S   3   1.00
      3.42525091             0.15432897       
      0.62391373             0.53532814       
      0.16885540             0.44463454      
****
$end
```

For the actual fitting procedure, i.e. minimising $\eqref{min-int}$ you should consult a more technical oriented network page. It might be on topic at [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), or even [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) depending on the question that troubles you. Please check their guidelines before asking.

---

### General remarks

The most principle shortcoming of GTOs is that they cannot describe the cusp correctly. It's a trade-off you just make for faster integral evaluation. With STO-6G you are getting the orbital quite right already and there is a reason why we usually use STO-3G and not some higher contraction. It just offers the best cost : accuracy ratio.
This can be quite neatly seen in the graphical representation. The black curve  is the original STO, purple is STO-6G, cyan is STO-4G, and red is STO-2G plotted online at the wonderful FooPlot. Hack it [here](http://fooplot.com/#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) (I hope that works).

[image: STO, STO-(6/4/2)G]

Going from STO-6G to STO-7G won't give you much more accuracy, maybe not even going to STO-10G. You probably have to go more into the direction of STO-20/30G. At that point it is probably more economic to switch to a program that can handle STO natively. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum_chemistry_and_solid-state_physics_software) I see two, that handle those: [ADF](https://www.scm.com/), and [MolDS](https://osdn.net/projects/molds/). The latter seems young, but is free.

#### Addendum:

If the FooPlot link does not work, here are the used formulae:

```
(1/pi)^(1/2)*exp(-abs(x))

0.679*(2*0.152/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-0.152*x^2)+
0.430*(2*0.852/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-0.852*x^2)

0.292*(2*0.088/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-0.088*x^2)+
0.533*(2*0.265/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-0.265*x^2)+
0.260*(2*0.955/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-0.955*x^2)+
0.0568*(2*5.22/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-5.22*x^2) 

0.130*(2*0.0651/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-0.0651*x^2)+
0.416*(2*0.158/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-0.158*x^2)+
0.371*(2*0.407/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-0.407*x^2)+
0.169*(2*1.19/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-1.19*x^2)+
0.0494*(2*4.24/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-4.24*x^2)+
0.00916*(2*23.1/pi)^(3/4)*exp(-23.1*x^2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution! Yes, we can find the STO-6G from textbooks or the paper you mentioned. After searching for a couple of days, I really cannot find the coefficients and exponents for STO-NG with N>6. I will see if I can work it out and share here.